# How to share my Realtime Database to someone to edit without sharing my firebase account?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to share my Realtime database to my friend to edit it and add some data,
but I don not want to share him my firebase account,
So is there any way to handle this issue,
and is it possible to share it to him using Firebase Realtime database reference URL?

Comment: Is the [Editor role on your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-basic) fulfilling your needs?

Comment: It is useful for me if there is an option to hide the analytics and let the member access only the real time database

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. The access is for "most Firebase products and services."

Answer (score 0):

You can add members(emails) by clicking on settings (left top corner)

Comment: Is there any way to hide analytics if I add member as editor ?